# How to access "textChanged" event from text box that added to telerik Rad Grid?

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid

Hi There Do you know how to access textboxes textChanged event added to a radgrid that are bound but are used to trap any row related input a user typed in to the textbox for that column. I need to access this data server side when a postback occurs. Your thoughts are greatly appreciated Thanking you

Answer (score 2):

Being in a RadGrid really doesn't change much. Set `AutoPostBack="true"` on the TextBox, and create an `OnTextChanged` event handler:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server">                                                                
    <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="false">      
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

In code-behind:

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt = sender as TextBox;
    if (txt != null)
    {
        //some logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: Actualy this is works fine in my test project. But unfortunately its not worked when I apply these things in to main project.It's given javascript error